# How to align a widget to other using RelativeLayout parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to align a linearlayout with the imageview horizontaly and I have RelativeLayout parent in my layout. I have to align my layout using relative layout.I dont want to use Constraint layout right now. I am focusing of how much flexible is relative layout so that I can get benfit of what it has.
when I use **android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_img"** to should be align , rignt now my product_img has margin top 20 dp but when i set my linear layout to **android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_img"** it only set it to the end side but again I need to set 20dp top margin to my this new  layout. why i am again and agian setting margin top in to each layout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white_alrt_box"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     />

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/cross_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_x"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/product_detail_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_img"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_img"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:text="@string/how_many"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_img"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:text="@string/how_many"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_detail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_img"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:text="@string/how_many"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Alignment issue respective to the imageview]

Comment: Do you want to set them in equal proportion?

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your `LinearLayout`.

```
android:layout_alignTop="@id/product_img"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code, please replace the image with yours and check.

I have just added

> android:layout_centerVertical="true"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"  // magic is here
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/cross_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/delete_category" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/product_detail_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" // magic is here
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_img"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hom Many you got?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hom Many you got?"
        android:textColor="@color/black_overlay_50"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hom Many you got?"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```